# Transaction Manager Is Not Available

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

i am using **`TransactionScope`** Class provided by .Net

However when i try to open connection it throws below exception.

```
{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004D01B): The Transaction Manager is not available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D01B)
```

Here is my code..

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=oratest2;Password=oratest2;Data Source=dr;Persist Security Info=False"))
     {
                    // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the  
                    // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
       connection1.Open(); // here it throws exception
     }
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at code posted here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/03/13/550856.aspx. You can find there different code samples for different *oledb* providers.

Comment: Check this: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-use-C-Net-TransactionScope-1931721.S.145921685 it might help you (check Juliano's answer).